# control torch brightness with react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, mobile-application

I am new to using react native to develop an iOS native application. I do not have access to a Apple development environment so I am using react native expo [Expo Camera](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/camera/) and expo app. I want to add a feature to control the device torch brightness using an on-screen slider. This is an important feature for the use case of the application.

The expo package does not have a property for controlling the torch brightness. I also explored external libraries but none have this property. I also checked out Flutter documentation [FlashMode](https://pub.dev/documentation/camera_platform_interface/latest/camera_platform_interface/FlashMode.html) but did not find anything relevant. What could be a possible solution for this?

Is there an external library available? If not I understand that I will have to write a package. However, I am not sure about the requirements and also exactly where to start for developing a library for the same.

Any help or advise is appreciated.
Thanks